# Always Probability of Hundred Percent: predict_proba, sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using Python's **sklearn** to classify texts.

I call the function `predict_proba` and it looks like this:

```
[[  6.74918834e-53   1.59981248e-51   2.74934762e-26   1.24948745e-43
    2.93801753e-48   3.43788315e-18   1.00000000e+00   2.96818867e-20]]
```

And even if I try to put in ambiguity data, it looks always like this.
It doesn't seem probable to me that the classfier is always hundred percent sure, so what's the problem there?

At the moment I'm using the **MultinomialNB** classifier and it's about **text classification**. I'm using **news paper articles** with classes like **sports**, **economy** etc. to train my model. The size of training examples is 175, distributed like this:

```
    {'business': 27,
     'economy': 20,
     'lifestyle': 22,
     'opinion': 11,
     'politics': 30,
     'science': 21,
     'sport': 21,
     'tech': 23}
```

My pipeline looks like this and my features are mainly **bag-of-words** and some linguistic key figures like text length.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1,1), max_features=1000)
tt = TfidfTransformer()
lv = LinguisticVectorizer() # custom class
clf = MultinomialNB()

pipeline = Pipeline([
('features', FeatureUnion([
  ('ngram_tf_idf', Pipeline([
    ('counts', cv),
    ('tf_idf', tt),
  ])),
('linguistic', lv),
])),
 ('scaler', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
 ('classifier', clf)
])
```

If you want to take a look at my training examples, I've uploaded it there: [wetransfer.com](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b17db309de53a565282e111f524b06dd20161122185544/5d690042d67665666492c8d4433a8b4f20161122185544/88249b)

**UPDATE:** Maybe it is worth mentioning that the current setup scores 0.67 on the test samples. But before using the `StandardScaler`, the probabilities was distributed more realistic (i.e. not always 100 percent) – but it scored only 0.2.

**UPDATE:** After adding a `MaxAbsScaler` in the pipeline, it seems to work correctly. Can someone explain this weird behaviour?

Comment: Can you share more details about what algorithm you used and what your data looks like? It's hard to answer your question only with what you have provided.

Comment: If you're using bag-of-words features with just 175 training samples, you probably have many more features than samples, which is a good recipe for overfitting without a properly tuned learner. To burhan's point, it's really tough to give any targeted feedback on this without working with your actual data though.

Comment: @RandyC: I've added my training samples. 
And even if the model is overfitting, if I input a text that contains words like "football", "business" and "climate", and these are all in the bag-of-word, I think the probability shouldn't be hundred percent for one of the classes...

Answer (score 2):

This means, especially given that it is Naive Bayes that at least one holds:

- you have a bug in your data processing routine, maybe you transform your whole document as a single word, instead of actually chunking it into parts? Check every single step to make sure that your documents are actually encoded on word level.
- your data is "corrupted" (there are unique words that uniquely identify your class), for example the newsgroups dataset originally consisted of **headers** information, where class name was literally specified (thus each document about sport had "group:sport@..." etc.)
- you have **huge** disproportion of classes, and simply your model is just predicting the majority class all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
I don't think there is a bug in the data processing routine. The current setup scores 0.67 on the test data (70 test samples) while having 7 classes, so it's significantly over random guesses.
I tried to prevent corrupt data using different newspaper sources, I also reviewed some articles to check the data quality and while there is some space to improve the data quality, there shouldn't be major issues like you mentioned.
The classes in the samples are nearly equally distributed (see OP), and the predicted class varies, but is always 100 percent.